# PHP4 to PHP5 deprecated functions

Tags: php

I have the following PHP4 script. Does an alternative exist to `session_register`, as this seems to be deprecated in PHP5. See code below.

Is there an easy way to rewrite this into valid PHP5 code, for it currently only works on PHP4 platforms.

```
<?php
Error_Reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

unset($l);
session_start();
session_register($l);
include ("includes/config.php");
include ("dbcon.php");
include ("includes/functions.php");
// CHECK AND UPDATE TRAFFIC STATS
$date=date("d/m/y");
$user_ip_address  =  $HTTP_SERVER_VARS["REMOTE_ADDR"]; /*Fetch the user's IP Address */
$traffic_stats=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from jsgamingcenter_traffic WHERE date='$date'", $casdb));
if ($traffic_stats[1]!=$date){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `jsgamingcenter_traffic` VALUES('', '$date', '0', '0')", $casdb);
}
$tuserip=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from jsgamingcenter_users WHERE ip_reg='$user_ip_address'", $casdb));
if ($tuserip[ip_reg]==$user_ip_address){
    mysql_query("UPDATE jsgamingcenter_traffic set visitors_re=visitors_re+'1' where date='$date'", $casdb);
}
if ($tuserip[ip_reg]!=$user_ip_address){
    mysql_query("UPDATE jsgamingcenter_traffic set visitors_new=visitors_new+'1' where date='$date'", $casdb);
}
/***********************************************************************
Check if user is logged on and display the appropriate page
************************************************************************/
if($page=="" or $page==" "){
    header("Location: casino_start.php");
}
if($page!="" && $page!=" "){
    if(!isset($l)){
        include ("templates/template_$page.php");  
    }
    else{
        include ("templates/template_$page.php");   
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: To be honest, you might have better luck rewriting the whole thing. A lot of the functions and language "features" you use are deprecated and even removed in modern versions of PHP.

Comment: @tyteen4a03 OP is asking what needs to be rewritten into what, I guess OP already knows which parts aren't working on PHP5

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php), write directly to [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php):

> You can also create a session variable by simply setting the
>   appropriate member of the $_SESSION or $HTTP_SESSION_VARS (PHP <
>   4.1.0) array.

---

As already mentioned by @tyteen4a03, you probably would be better of to rewrite that piece of code, as you use plenty of other deprecated stuff (from a first glance):

- `$HTTP_SERVER_VARS`
- `mysql_*()` functions